# .Net: Retrieving data from threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This is an Easy Q, but great help:

Under title" *Retrieving data from threads* MSDN ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52(VS.71).aspx)) introduces a way to get data from a child thread by using callback method which is encapsulated by a delegate passed from main thread to the child thread - who has the data.

You can see that clearly ( the last Example in the MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52(VS.71).aspx))

My Q is, since we are taking about retrieving data  (from child threads to main thread) the call back method should be executed by the main thread and not by the child thread...

I changed the code a bit ( to verify that) so I attached the name of the thread before each output:

```
 public static void ResultCallback(int lineCount) {
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ":Independent task printed {0} lines.", lineCount);  
}
```

And I named the child thread: "Method2" while the main thread "System"...

I got this output: **Method2**: Independent task printed 1 lines.

where the correct output should have been : **System**:Independent task printed 1 lines..

Who is drunk here?  MSDN, me or .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You" ;-p

Callbacks are still executed on the worker thread; they provide the data back to the calling **code** - but they don't have an inbuilt way of interrupting the calling **thread**. It is your code's responsibility to push that work back to the main thread if necessary. For example, in a winforms app you might have:

```
public static void ResultCallback(int lineCount) {
  // runs on worker thread
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
      // runs on UI thread
      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name +
         ":Independent task printed {0} lines.", lineCount);
  });
}
```

Comment: I got the first part
But didn't get how i puch the work back to the main thread!

Comment: What architecture are you using? winforms? web? wpf? console? service? It varies... with winforms, there is the Control.Invoke (shown above). With WPF/Silverlight, the Dispatcher - etc.

Comment: I am using console for my thread learning( Hmm that why it underlined the Invoke keyword)

Comment: There is no inbuilt way of doing that with a console exe - your main thread would have to be watching a queue (or similar) to get updates. Of course, being a console exe, it might not matter as much in the first place... (winforms etc have thread affinity; console - not so much).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want/need to use callbacks and the data is fairly small you can always use shared memory and C# lock keyword.

Maciej.